# Post request with JSON, but server side has Request.Form.Count == 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, post, request.form

I'm trying to send JSON with POST method from console application to WebPage.aspx
which will regonize JSON and will do somethink with data.
Request status is OK, but on server side I'm getting empty Request.form (not null just count = 0). 
But server will need to read data from. Code which I wrote just is the prototype of integration with another page, thats why I need to send data in Request.form.

Cah you help to fix my post?

```
    public async static void KeepMeLogged()
    {
         string urlPart = "ReadJson";
         string BaseUrl = "https://baseurl/external-api/"
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
         new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    ForRequest json = new ForRequest
    {
        Login = Login
    };

    try
    {
        string stringJson = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json));
        var httpContent = new StringContent(stringJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Do the actual request and await the response
            var httpResponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(BaseUrl + urlPart, httpContent);

            // If the response contains content we want to read it!
            if (httpResponse.Content != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("IsOk");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

public class ForRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("login")]
    public string Login { get; set; }
}

//ServerSide, Request.Form.Count always 0
public partial class ReadJsonPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form != null)
        {

            foreach (string key in Request.Form)
            {
                   //Request.Form.Count == 0
                   //do something
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's normal to post json to an endpoint when it's in the same domain/url. But posting from a console app to a web endpoint. I believe you might have CORS issues.

Comment: unfortunately I need to adapt to api, because it will be integration with external soft, so  it's not my solution :(

Answer (score 2):

You can get your json data with this code:

```
Request.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
using (var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
{
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But server will need to read data from. Code which I wrote just is the prototype of integration with another page, that why I need to send data in Request.form. I need to fix my post

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, how to send JSON in Request.form

```
MyClass json = new MyClass
{
    Login = Login
};

string stringLogin = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logIn));

string URI = BaseUrl + urlPart;
string myParameters = "json=" + stringLogin;
try
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, "POST", myParameters);
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(HtmlResult);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: "json=" it's just a name of parametr